# Keeping the public key password for duration of script

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, ssh-keys

Is there a way of keeping the public key password for the duration of a shell script?

I'm building a deploy script which needs to clear caches etc before actually transmitting files. And after that I need to run a command on the server too. Both these action require me to enter a password and I only want to do that once at the beginning of the script. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that with ssh-add/ssh-agent (included with OpenSSH). Once you have used ssh-add to type your password once and add the key to agent, any scp/ssh commands that follow won't prompt for a password as long as it can communicate with the ssh-agent (via the SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable). Make sure you use the "-k" option with ssh-add so that the agent will expire the password after a suitable time.

Comment: sound promising, i'll look into that later